# Matlab: deleting inverted comma in cellarray

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

I have an cellarray with Strings in this form:

A =

```
 'test'

 'b'

 'abc'
```

My problem is that I don't need the inverted comme in the array. I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: By "inverted comma", do you mean the single quote `'` ? If so, you should know that it is only there to remind you that these cells contain strings.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Matlab **do** puts single quotes around the string if retrived from a cell array using smooth parenthesis.

Consider c = {'tree','hepp','birch'}

if you get values from the cell array using c(1) matlab will return 'tree'.

The **solution** is to use *curly braces: c{1}* and Matlab will return tree without single quotes.

You can read more about how to access data in cell arrays here:
[Cell Arrays, Matlab Documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-117)

As pointed out there smooth parentheses refer to sets of cells, used for example to define a subset of the array. Curly braces refer to the text, numbers or other data within individual cells.

Comment: Good points. I deleted my answer (in case anyone wonders what this answer's first sentence refers to).